# Transform Json strings in dataframe to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert a column that has json strings into multiple columns from the json data.
Example data :

```
       1
  0
id1    {"c1": ["a","b"], "c2": [.1, .2], "c3": ["3","1"]}
id2    {"c1": ["c","d"], "c2": [.7, .4], "c3": ["8","4"]}
```

How would I turn it into :

```
    c1  c2  c3
id1 a  .1   3
    b  .2   1
id2 c  .7   8
    d  .4   4
```

How to achieve this with pandas functions only?

Comment: Are source data `json` and then call `pd.DataFrame(json)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dictionary comprehension` with `ast.literal_eval` for convert strings to dictioanries and lists:

```
import ast

df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(v)) for k, v in df[1].items()})
print (df)
      c1   c2 c3
id1 0  a  0.1  3
    1  b  0.2  1
id2 0  c  0.7  8
    1  d  0.4  4
```

If need remove `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
    c1   c2 c3
id1  a  0.1  3
id1  b  0.2  1
id2  c  0.7  8
id2  d  0.4  4
```